# Azure service bus - combining SQL and Correlation filter

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I couldn't find in in the docs, but the behaviour is not what I would expect.
[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters#filters) it's written:

> When specifying multiple match properties, the filter combines them as a logical AND condition, meaning for the filter to match, all conditions must match.

But it seems that it only concerns multiple correlation filters.
When I've defined SQL filter along with correlation filter it seemed like only 1 was used.
Can anyone point to specific place in docs where it's defined? I.e. how it exactly works - which filter is evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining multiple rules for a subscription, the rules are OR-ed. I.e. it's enough for a single rule to be evaluated as truthy for the message to be sent to a subscription.

Comment: Could you provide any reference?

Comment: See the document you've linked to. It states "All rules without actions are combined using an OR condition and result in a single message on the subscription even if you have multiple matching rules."